# Power BI - Mapbox visual not showing lines anymore after update - January 2024

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

I was able to use Mapbox Visual on PowerBI, to show lines that were imported on the Mapbox Studio website.

Now suddenly the lines are not showing anymore and there are not errors appearing, just the map without any Mapbox element.

**- Until a couple of weeks ago:**

[image]

**- Now:**

- On Mapbox Studio: *I have to choose a version to use on Settings, but none of them works properly on PowerBI once I publish the map.*
  [image]
  [image]

*But, even if I choose a version and the warning disappear, once I publish the map, no lines appear on PowerBi visual.*

[image]